# With the Foxit Web SDK is it possible to get not just the data but the entire document server-side

Tags: foxit

When a PDF with form fields is rendered in the Foxit web viewer (WEB SDK product), and then is completed by the user, signed, and submitted, is it possible for server-side code to get the bytes of the completed document, not just the data from its form fields?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example you are using Java in the backend. I guess in your scenario, your PDFs are hosted on the server(like you have 10 registration forms on the server and your customer can fill them out online). Since those files are on the server, just use Java to read them from the file system using its path. Something like this,
[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

If this scenario does not well describe what you have, please share part of your code and I will be more than happy to help.